# Regex for extracting name in school cards

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract and display the name on a school card:

```
Jennifer Ng Si En
Female
Singaporean

Nanyang Polytechnic

Tel: 65523325
HP: 96655523
Email: igfdjh@edikfjh.sg
```

I know a true name regex is quite impossible as it will require a dictionary of all the names in the world to truly extract the name.

So this is my current regex:

```
^(?!.*\b(Polytechnic|University|Institute|School|Faculty|Technology|Engineering)\b) *[A-Za-z][A-Za-z.]*(?: +[A-Za-z.]+){1,3} *$
```

What is does is take in any phrase that has 1 to 4 words and exclude phrase that contains "Polytechnic, University, Institute, School, Faculty, Technology or Engineering" which are words that often shows up on a school card.

It can successfully extract out the name " Jennifer Ng Si En". However, let's say the name contains a "," **(eg: Ng Si En, Jennifer)**.

It will then fail to extract the name "Ng Si En, Jennifer".

How do I edit my regex to include this function whether it can also take in names that contains a "," while also take in name without ","?

Comment: Following your logic, add the `,` to `[A-Za-z.]`: `[A-Za-z.,]`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hU3tO5/1)

Comment: I hope that this name is not a real name :/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks :)

Comment: @Seth It is not, just a name I make up myself for this example

Comment: This is the third or fourth time this question has come up.

Comment: @JimGarrison: If you downvoted my answer, that is really inappropriate: if it is working, it is certainly helpful. I could just delete it if you marked the question as a dupe. Where is the original question?

Comment: Perhaps he is referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35171915/regex-for-matching-educational-institutes. That's the question I thought of when I saw this.

Comment: @AndyTurner: I am one of those who closed that question because it showed no efforts. In my opinion, this one is quite different. The regex in the current question is more advanced that the one in the accepted answer in the previous question.

Comment: Well, ok, I don't know which one he's thinking of then :) I wasn't the downvoter, BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your logic, add the literal `,` to `[A-Za-z.]` character classes:

```
^(?!.*\b(Polytechnic|University|Institute|School|Faculty|Technology|Engineering)\b) *[A-Za-z][A-Za-z.,]*(?: +[A-Za-z.,]+){1,3} *$
                                                                                                     ^               ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hU3tO5/1)

Note that you may use `[A-Za-z]\S*` instead of `[A-Za-z][A-Za-z.,]*` to match any non-whitespace symbols, zero or more occurrences, after a letter.

If you want to exclude matching "words" like `Je,nnifer`, use

```
^(?!.*\b(Polytechnic|University|Institute|School|Faculty|Technology|Engineering)\b) *[A-Za-z][A-Za-z.]*(?:,? +[A-Za-z.]+){1,3} *$
                                                                                                          ^^
```

The `,?` matches one or zero commas. See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/hU3tO5/2).

Do not forget to use double escapes in Java string literals.

**@Downvoter**: Downvoting working answers without leaving comments is meaningless.

Comment: The second demo was really helpful, I was actually testing for Je,nnifer too, when I first tested your answer in the comments